# How do I get a progress element that was animated to resize on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, window-resize

I'm trying to get the animated progress span inside the wrapper (meter) div to resize like the other elements when you resize window after it has already animated.  See in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/py4btbna/) - if you resize window smaller the `.meter > span` stays put but all other elements are resizing properly. When I added window.resize function it just made the animation whacky.

HTML:

```
<div class="skill">
    <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 98%"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="skillname">Painting</div>
</div>
<div class="skill">
    <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 96%"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="skillname">Drawing</div>
</div>
<div class="skill">
    <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 93%"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="skillname">Photography</div>
</div>
<div class="skill">
    <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 90%"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="skillname">Sculpture</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.meter {
    height: 16px;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #DCD9D6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 1px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.meter > span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #2F474E;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.skillname {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".meter > span").each(function (i) {
    $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
        width: $(this).delay(200 * i).data("origWidth")
    }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that JS will convert it into a computed width, rather than the percent set in your CSS. You could write something with window-resize, but it might over complicate it.

Instead you could just reset the width after your .each() loop to be back to the % (which unfortunately, is not straight forward).  You can compute it yourself.  You will need to add a promise to ensure that it happens after the animation:

```
$(".meter > span").each(function(i) {
    $(this)
    .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
    .width(0)
    .animate({
      width: $(this).delay(200*i).data("origWidth") 
    }, 800); 
}).promise().done(function(){
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this).width(Math.round(( 100 * parseFloat($(this).css('width')) /  parseFloat($(this).parent().css('width')) )) + '%');
    });
});
```

So, we simply take the current width, divided by the width of the parent times 100 and slap a % sign on the end.  Then use the css property in jQuery to add it to each bar.  Seems to work for me.

You can view the JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jeaku9k9/1/